# Will Postgres handle the Unix Epoch problem?

Tags: postgresql, dbms

I was wondering if Postgres will be handling the unix epoch problem coming in 2038? I have read about this and am wondering.

It's about a productivity thing obviously because it is so far away, but I am curious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html in the documentation it displays data about the `to_timestamp` function that returns a `timestamp with time zone` value from an epoch value. Complete description is: "Convert Unix epoch (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00) to timestamp"

The input type of the function is `double precision`.

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-numeric.html you can see that `double precision` is defined as `8 bytes` with 15 decimal digits precision.
A little down below you can read:

> The double precision type typically has a range of around 1E-307 to 1E+308 with a precision of at least 15 digits.

So `1E+308` seconds after `1970-01-01` should carry you far after 2038...

In fact if you look at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TodoDone84, which lists all features that have been done in PostgreSQL 8.4 you can see:

> Completed item: Extend timezone code to allow 64-bit values so we can represent years beyond 2038

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about it, because they have added the beyond the year 2038 support more than ten years ago (!) in 8.4 release (2009):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/release-8-4.html

Comment: The accepted answer already contains that information.